# Overriding a function only for certain types in template

Tags: c++, templates, overriding

I have a base class with a virtual function:

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual void Function();
};

void Base::Function()
{
  cout << "default version" << endl;
}
```

and a derived template class:

```
template <class T> class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  virtual void Function();
};
```

Is there a way to make `Function()` be taken from the base class for all types, except some chosen ones? So what I want is to be able to define an overriden `Function()` for, say, `int` and `long`:

```
void Derived<int>::Function()
{
  cout << "overriden version 1" << endl;
}

void Derived<long>::Function()
{
  cout << "overriden version 2" << endl;
}
```

and to have the default version of `Function()` for all other types, without explicit definition of `Function()` for them, so the output of

```
int main ()
{
  Derived<int> derivedInt;
  derivedInt.Function();

  Derived<long> derivedLong;
  derivedLong.Function();

  Derived<double> derivedDouble;
  derivedDouble.Function();
}
```

would be

```
overriden version 1
overriden version 2
default version
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 8):

Member functions of class templates are in fact function templates, so you can specialize them:

```
template <typename T> class Foo
{
    void Function();
};

template <typename T> void Foo::Function() { /* ... */ }

template <> void Foo<int>::Function() { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: If applying this to the original problem, the unspecialized `Derived::Function()` would be defined but just call `Base::Function()`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, by specializing `Derived`.

- write the generic version without it (it will inherit it from `Base`)
- specialize `Derived` to override

Simple scheme, but it works.

Answer (score 4):

**First solution** (use of the `typeid` operator)**:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void Function();
};

void Base::Function()
{
    cout << "default version\n";
}

template<typename T>
class Derived : Base
{
public:
    virtual void Function();
};

template<typename T>
void Derived<T>::Function()
{
    if(typeid(T) == typeid(int)) // check if T is an int
    {
        cout << "overriden version 1\n";
    }
    else if(typeid(T) == typeid(long)) // check if T is a long int
    {
        cout << "overriden version 2\n";
    }
    else // if T is neither an int nor a long
    {
        Base::Function(); // call default version
    }
}

int main()
{
    Derived<int> di;
    Derived<long> dl;
    Derived<float> df;

    di.Function();
    dl.Function();
    df.Function();

    return 0;
}
```

I use the `typeid` operator to check if T is either an `int` or a `long int`, and if it is, I print "overriden version [number]". If it is not, I call `Base::Function()`, which will print "default version"

**Note:** to use the `typeid` operator you need to include the header file `typeinfo`

**Second solution** (using template specializations)**:**

```
// class declarations as before

template<typename T>
void Derived<T>::Function()
{
    Base::Function(); // call default version
}

template<>
void Derived<int>::Function()
{
    cout << "overriden version 1\n";
}

template<>
void Derived<long>::Function()
{
    cout << "overriden version 2\n";
}

int main()
{
    Derived<int> di;
    Derived<long> dl;
    Derived<float> df;

    di.Function();
    dl.Function();
    df.Function();

    return 0;
}
```

Here, I solve your problem with template specializations. If T is either an `int` or a `long int`, I call the specialized versions. Else, i call the general version, which is equivalent to `Base::Function()`.

Comment: IMO implementing a virtual function using else-if-heimer's is a step backwards.